# Field Data vs Origin Summary

Tags: performance, pagespeed

I have measured performance for a handful of my sites. Some are larger and get more traffic than others. One of my smaller sites, which I am aware does not get a lot of traffic, does not show field data metrics but does show origin summary metrics.
If the origin summary is an aggregate data measurement and field data comes from CrUX, what is the difference?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SSrG.png) Isn't the CrUX report and aggregate of the same numbers and metrics where the origin summary is getting its data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Field data is for **specific page**.

Origin Summary is for **entire domain.**

So even though it is fetching from CrUX report it does not sufficient number of distinct samples that provide a representative, anonymized data for that page.